# No data loaded from RDFXML files both via bulk or workbench

Tags: graphdb

I evaulating GraphDB and got into situation where none data loaded in newly created repository. By using pure RDF4J open source system I am able to load all files without any issue, but in GraphDB it is telling me that 0 statements parsed and when executing SPARQL query it returns 0.

I tried both the workbench and also the loadrdf tool as I am interested especially in load performance now:

```
./loadrdf -f -i rdf-experiment -m serial -verbose -s /home/zangetsu/devel/proj/rdfprocessor/src/main/resources/rdf_batch/*_EQ_*

// Logs
https://pastebin.com/dihVsS4z
// Example RDFXML file
https://pastebin.com/2xqCWjs6
```

I don't see any helping info in the log file.

Here is example file:

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see from your logs that the file extention was '.xml' so it is very likely that 'loadrdf' tool selected a wrong parser based on it (e.g. autodetected it as in TriX format instead of RDFXML). You could try to rename your rdf files to '.rdf' and check again.

Comment: Parsed 1,799,342 statements in 28,908 ms ! Nice, thank you very much.

Comment: Can I somehow configure the parser manually or it is only autodetected?

Comment: At present, it is only autodetected. Internally, 'loadrdf' uses RDF4J's list of registered parsers and their respective FileFormat descriptions to select a parser based on the file extention. Both TriX and RDFXML paresrs register '.xml' file extention but the TriX parser uses it as 'default' so it is selected when the file is processed. Enumerating other avaliable alternatives on parsing failures is not yet implemented.

Comment: Thank you. Well the benchamark of loadrdf tool in parallel mode vs by hand written RDF4J multithreaded processor with Native (disk based) repository resulted at RDF4J being faster then bulk load tool of GraphDB, we discuss the high performance RDF processing (parse, load, query) here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rdf4j-users/mvYKSlodgDA for those being interested